# Framebuffer object alternatives?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I've recently decided to start learning OpenGL, and I got into the LazyFoo tutorials. However I ran into a problem with rendering to textures through framebuffer objects [as described here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/27_frame_buffer_objects_and_render_to_texture/index.php), since my computer only supports up to OpenGL 1.4 (yes I updated my drivers) which doesn't support functions like glGenFramebuffers() and glBindFramebuffer().

Are there alternative ways for me to render to anything other than the backbuffer?

Comment: OpenGL-1.4 sounds eerily much like Windows-Vista/7/8 no-proper-OpenGL-driver fallback. Also today you'll be hard pressed finding a system that doesn't support OpenGL-2.1 or FBOs at least through an extension. *Do not update your drivers through __Windows Update__, that doesn't get the job done. You must download the drivers manually from your GPU maker's website and install those.*

Comment: Oh, and even drivers for the most ancient OpenGL capable hardware (like the first GeForce cards) retroactively got FBO extension support; the capabilities always were there, through PBuffers (see Reto's answer), FBOs just make accessing that much easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is an older mechanism for off-screen rendering called PBuffer (pixel buffer).

It works quite differently from FBO because creating a PBuffer is not part of the OpenGL API itself. You create a PBuffer using the window system interface, which is platform dependent. You will for example use functions from the WGL family under Windows, GLX on Unix/Linux based systems, EGL on Android, etc, to set up PBuffers.

Related to this, you also use a separate context to render to the PBuffer. So you can't just switch between render targets within the same context. At least some window system interfaces allow you to use the result of PBuffer rendering as a texture in a different context.

Since this is highly platform dependent, I won't try to elaborate in detail on how PBuffers are used (frankly, it has also been a very long time since I used them, so the memory is fuzzy). But here are a couple of pointers to get you started:

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXCreatePbuffer.xml
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/WGL_EXT_pbuffer.txt
https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreatePbufferSurface.xhtml

Comment: EGL allows to use this on any system, not just Android. I, for instance, successfully use it on Ubuntu — binding OpenGL API, not GLES.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Accumulation Buffer?

http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse872/tutorial5.html

Comment: There's a part in there that worries me; it mentions that the accumulation buffer is extremely slow and is not meant for real-time rendering.

Comment: Other than the accumulation buffer, I don't know of any other solutions. Have you tried upgrading your computer?

Comment: I would like to upgrade my computer, but living in Europe makes getting parts a lot more complicated. And then there's the money issue, I only have a few hundred extra spending cash atm.

Comment: @TakingItCasual: What kind of computer (and especially GPU) do you even have that you are limited to opengl 1.4 in 2014?

Comment: It's a really old computer, something I got for under a hundred euros from a thrift shop. The chipset is Intel G33 and the video card is a PCI Express x16.

Comment: @TakingItCasual GPU aren't that expensive, and you could get a great upgrade for the money. And there's plenty of sites to buy European computer parts. You just have to know where to look.

Comment: @TakingItCasual: Define "really old". When talking OpenGL-1.4 we're talking previous millenium grade stuff. Anything that's been made after 2000 supports OpenGL-1.5 and everything made after 2004 does OpenGL-2.1, so it takes not just old, but antique hardware for a OpenGL profile that limited.